# Beautiful Soup issue with webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraping project and I have the following item that I plan to web scrape:

```
<td class="country">
  <div>
    <img alt="Niger" height="27" src="http://assets.rio2016.nbcolympics.com/country-flags/52x35/NIG.png" width="40"/>
    Niger                                          
  </div>
```

In this case, I am trying to get the country Niger out of the list. I have a whole table where I am trying to pull all of the countries out. The current code that I have looks like the following:

```
response = requests.get('http://www.nbcolympics.com/medals')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
for td in soup.findAll("td",{"class": "country"}):
   print(td)
```

This will get me way to much information. I just want to focus in on the country value within the table. (This table has all countries who competed in the Olympics.) If I try to do something like:

```
for td in soup.findAll("td",{"class": "country"}).children:
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "idea.py", line 15, in <module>
  for row in soup.find_all('tr').children:
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'children'
```

I know that there has to be a way that I can look through each of these td's to pull out the country value. (I can get the country using get_text() but there is a lot more information that comes with it.) Also, if the div value had a class then I think it would be fairly easy to do as well. Thank you for any help.

I have also tried:

```
for td in soup.findAll("img", {"width": "40"})
      print(td)
```

which almost gets me what I want. It will print the following:

```
<img alt="Togo" height="27" src="http://assets.rio2016.nbcolympics.com/country-flags/52x35/TOG.png" width="40"/>
```

However, I am not getting the country right after it! But I am just about there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` returns a `ResultSet` of found elements, which is an iterable. You need to loop over the found elements and access `.text`:

```
for element in soup.findAll("img", {"class": "country"}):
    print(element.get('alt', ''))
```

I have replaced the `"td",{"class": "country"}` selector, since you're looking for an image with the class `country`.

Comment: Yes, I updated to show what happens when you use the img tag-it almost gets me what I want but stops right before the country. So, it just about gets me what I want but not quite! Thank you for the help!

Comment: I have updated my answer, it should fix your problem. Next time try to google "beautifulsoup get image alt", and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Got it, that appears to have worked! Thank you!